# Flickr API get a limited number of comments

Tags: api, flickr

I'm using the Flickr API's flickr.photos.comments.getList method to get a list of comments of some photos from their site. The photos I am using are off of the flickr.interestingness.getList method and generally have hundreds of comments and favorites. I'd only like to get 8 comments per request, is there a way to do this?

Also, I need some clarification on the min_comment_date vs max_comment_date arguments. Say I want to get only photos within the last 24 hours, which argument would I use and what would I supply to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,the flickr api doesn't allow list restrictions of comments via the web service api. 
Other commands have limiters like page/per_page, but not the comments-list; at least not at the moment.

About the date arguments: flickr accepts a unix timestamp or mysql datetime for the date fields, also in this case. Normally you can create the timestamps programatically in most programming languages, for testing you can convert values manually via http://www.unixtimestamp.com.

hope this helps.